# code for converting px values to % in html/css using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, percentage, pixel

I have a long css document that has px values that I need to convert to % values.

I am looking for a quick solution without having to change each value one by one.

Was wondering is there any JS code for automatically converting those values on the fly when the page loads?

So for example

Page container has a max width of 1000px, the news-div is 300px. So I would need to the JS to do the maths and convert the news-div value to 30%

Does something like this even exist?

Thanks

Comment: can't you do find and replace?

Comment: I would still need to go through each value one by one and do the maths manually. Was just wondering if there's a quicker solution

Answer (score 2):

`(300 * 100) / 1000` where 300 is the number you want percentage for and 1000 is the total number

So 500 is 50% of 1000
`(500 * 100) / 1000 = 50`

Answer (score 2):

Percentage is a relative value as per my knowledge.
Just with one value like 100 px you cannot make percentage because you need to have relative value like screenWidth which is always different and by that you can make percentage.

You can do this :

---

```
var pixels = 100;
var screenWidth = window.screen.width;
var percentage = ( screenWidth - pixels ) / screenWidth ;
```

---